# Can't access XSLT file

Tags: css, xml, vb.net, xslt, rss

Having some trouble with picking up my XSL sheet when generating the RSS feed on my website.

I'm doing this through the code behind in VB but when the RSS is generated it's all coming through in one line.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Public Sub RssFeed(ByVal cxt As HttpContext)
    Dim outString As String = ""
    cxt.Response.Clear()
    cxt.Response.ContentType = "application/rss+xml"
    cxt.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    Using xw As New XmlTextWriter(cxt.Response.OutputStream, Text.Encoding.UTF8)

        xw.WriteStartDocument()
        'processing instruction to style the rss
        Dim PIText As String = "type=""text/xsl"" href=""Styles/rss.xsl"""
        xw.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", PIText)

        xw.WriteStartElement("rss")
        xw.WriteAttributeString("version", "2.0")
        xw.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "atom", Nothing, "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")

        'channel contains all the RSS feed details
        xw.WriteStartElement("channel")

        xw.WriteStartElement("atom:link")
        xw.WriteAttributeString("stuff")

        xw.WriteEndElement()

        xw.WriteElementString("title")
        xw.WriteElementString("link")
        xw.WriteElementString("description")
        xw.WriteElementString("language", "en-gb")

        xw.WriteStartElement("category")
        xw.WriteAttributeString("domain")
        xw.WriteString("Event Log")
        xw.WriteEndElement()

        'db connection stuff
```

**EDIT 2**

When inspecting the element through Chrome under the network tab, the type is 'text/plain' - so it's not recognising the filer as RSS/XML.

I updated the code above to contain the line `cxt.Response.ClearHeaders()` but this hasn't altered how the browser is interpreting the file.

**EDIT 2**

As requested here is the simplified XSLT sheet I'm using.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.1">
  <xsl:output method="html" />
  <xsl:variable name="title" select="/rss/channel/title"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/rss.css" type="text/css"/>
      </head>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="rss/channel"/>
    </html>
 </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="channel">
    <body>
      <h2>heading</h2>
      <h6>small heading</h6>
      <table border ="1">
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="#7DCC3D">Title</td>
          <td bgcolor="#333366">Link</td> 
          <td bgcolor="#7DCC3D">Description</td> 
          <td bgcolor="#333366">Published</td> 
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item">
          <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="link"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="pubDate"/></td>   
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </body>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what the problem is? Is the stylesheet not applied? Can you show us the stylesheet code? Can you show us the RSS source your code generates?

Comment: Apologies - the sheet is there, I can access it through the browser, the stylesheet isn't being applied. Very basic XSLT to see if I can get it working, is there a setting I may need to change in IIS to get it so it understands XSLT?

Comment: If you send XML with the `xml-stylesheet` processing instruction to the browser then it is the browser that applies the XSLT client-side, it is not IIS. I would start checking the error console of your browser whether it shows any error or warning messages. If you have a public URL we can check you can also post it.

Comment: IIS comes first though, so if IIS doesn't interpret it as an XML/RSS file it would send it to the browser as a plain text file wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think it's something to do with IIS; if you remove the `rss+` from the `cxt.Response.ContentType = "application/rss+xml"` then the XSLT will be rendered.

I will look into why this is the problem and update my answer when I find out.